# Angular compilation - Module build failed

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass, build

Getting below error while compiling my Angular Application

```
./src/styles.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[1].use[1]!./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
5 │ @use "include-media";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 5:1  root stylesheet
```

Styles were included from Local repo,

Package.json

```
"@xxxx/ngstyle": "file:../xxxx.ngstyle/dist/xxxx/ngstyle",
```

```
@include ngstyle.init();
```

My @xxxx.ngstyle has sass 1.45.0
package.json

```
  "include-media": "^1.4.10",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.45.0",
```

This is happening with application build. Compilation happens, If I include ngstyle's package version instead of local path. But there is no difference between published ngstyle & my local code.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine after adding "include-media": "^1.4.10", in package.json file, since it is mentioned as peerdependencies in ngstyle library.